# How can I replace the default blank template in PowerPoint with my customised template?

Tags: templates, powerpoint

I copied and pasted the customised template in the users/appdata, but the template is not reflected in PowerPoint after the process, but it's working for other user

I copy pasted the customised template in the template path where blank template is present and was expecting the customised template to show up instead of blank template, but the customised template is not showing up, I tried the same thing with my colleague's system it's working I couldn't figure out the issue

Comment: This was written for Office 2013, but might be a good starting point:  https://echosvoice.com/how-to-set-a-default-template-in-powerpoint-2013/